# git branch -m erasing commits

Tags: git, github

I created a local repository with a bunch of commits (at least 15). Then, I decided to push the commits to a GitHub repo, using `git remote add origin <link to github repo>`. Then, I checked `git log` and I could successfully see all my commits. However, I then entered `git branch -M main`. When I entered `git log`, I got the error `fatal: your current branch 'main' does not have any commits yet`.

I tried `git checkout master` but that gave me the error `error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git`. I also tried `git branch -a` and that gave me nothing. When, I go inside my local repository, inside the file `.git\logs\HEAD`, I can see all my commits. But I'm not being able to see it on the terminal and push it to GitHub.

Comment: If you want a good idea about what happened try to run `gitk --all &`, that way you can see the current state of your repo for all branches. You might also want to run `git reflog` that let's you see the history of which commit you have been at (meaning you could check out a specific commit from its ID)

Comment: Forgot to ask if your current state of the repository is missing all the files from the commits. I assumed they were missing since `git log` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Kim (off-topic) I had to research what was that `&` at the end of your shell command, and now I learned a new neat bash trick. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't say why the issue occurred in the first place. To resolve the issue, you could:

- Checkout to the detached commit ID from reflog using `git checkout <commit ID>`. Verify all your changes exist.
- Delete the main branch with `git branch -D main`.
- Create main branch from the current commit ID with `git checkout -b main`.

Comment: I was able to copy the first commit ID from `.git\logs\HEAD` and then did `git checkout <commit ID>`, followed by `git reflog`. Turns out I had a detached HEAD, which I was able to fix through some Googling.

Comment: (As a sidenote, `git checkout -B main` would group your two last steps. Even further, `git checkout -B main <commit-hash-from-reflog>` would group the three steps altogether, but the post-step1 check makes sense)